# Gradle does not pick correct version of war file in Jenkins

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, maven-deploy-plugin

I have an issue with Gradle which is used to deploy spring boot application to cloud foundry. maven.deployer does not pick the correct version of war file as per the naming convention specified in the gradle. War file is created successfully in build/distributions, but it is not getting picked correctly by uploadarchive task. Any help would be great.

Getting error:

```
:uploadArchives (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.378 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Error deploying artifact 'com.*****:***-SSO_RC:war': Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://*******/releases/com****-SSO_RC/0.1.0/****-SSO_RC-0.1.0.war. Return code is: 400

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Build.gradle

```
version "0.1.0"  //Art added Snapshot to version
group "com*****"

project.ext.test = 'test'

// Define property defaults if they don't exist
if( !project.hasProperty('classifier' ) ){
    ext.classifier = 'LOCAL'
}
if( !project.hasProperty('buildNumber' ) ){
    ext.buildNumber = '0'
}

ext.isSnapshot = (ext.classifier == "RELEASE" || ext.classifier.contains("RC" ) ) ? false : true

apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'cloudfoundry'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        //mavenCentral()
        maven { url  nexusPublicRepoURL }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE")
        classpath "org.cloudfoundry:cf-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    }
}


// Uses JDK 7
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


// 1. Get dependencies from Maven local repository
// 2. Get dependencies from Maven central repository
repositories {
    maven { url  nexusPublicRepoURL }
    //mavenCentral()
}

//Project dependencies
dependencies {
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
    //include in compile only, exclude in the war
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5' 
    // compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    //providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}

/*configurations {
    providedRuntime
}*/

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}


uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: nexusReleaseRepoURL) {
             logger.info("${nexusReleaseRepoURL} is nexusReleaseRepoURL")
            authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: nexusSnapshotRepoURL) {
            authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
        }
    }
}

if( project.hasProperty( 'development' ) ){
    cloudfoundry{
        host = '***-ssodev'
        space = 'development'
        target = 'https://api.****.com'
        domain = '****.com'
        env = [
        "JBP_LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG"
        ]
        services {
            "syslog-drain" {
                label ="syslog-drain"
            }

        }
    }
} else if ( project.hasProperty( 'production' ) ) {
    cloudfoundry {
        host = '***-sso'
        space = 'production'
        target = 'https://api.*****.com'
        domain = '****.com'

        services {
            "syslog-drain" {
                label ="syslog-drain"
            }

        }
    }
}

cloudfoundry {
    username = cfUsername
    password = cfPassword
    application = '****'
    //file = war.outputFile
    file = file("build/distributions/" + buildArchiveName())
    logger.info("${file} is file inside Cloudfoundry")
    memory = 1024
    instances = 1
    organization = "***-org"
    trustSelfSignedCerts = "true"
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = '<%= packageName %>.Application'
 }

war {
    archiveName = buildArchiveName()
    logger.info("${archiveName} is archiveName")
    destinationDir = file('build/distribution/')
}   

def buildArchiveName(){
    if( project.hasProperty('archiveBuildNumber' ) ){
        return "****sso-${version}-${classifier}.${archiveBuildNumber}.war".toString()
    }
    else {
        return "****sso-${version}-${classifier}.${buildNumber}.war".toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: The cloudfoundry tag on this question is misleading, as the uploadArchives task has nothing to do with Cloud Foundry.

Comment: the issue is resolved for me. I was new to the gradle, the solution implemented is just add everything as version instead of keeping it different like version+classifier+buildNumber(jenkin). war task should be like basename + version instead of calling the archiveName.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is resolved for me. I was new to the gradle, the solution implemented is just add everything as version instead of keeping it different like version+classifier+buildNumber(jenkin). war task should be like basename + version instead of calling the archiveName.